# jQuery UI: sortable and draggable + sortable and droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two lists. They are sortable but not connected (elements of list "one" cannot be mixed with elements of list "two")

I want elements of list "one" be droppable and elements of list "two" be draggable, because I want to drag and drop element of list "two" into list "one".

How should I do?

**EDIT:**

I tried to make the question as general as possible but maybe I should be more clear... sorry.
Elements of list one are "categories" and they should be sortable. 
Elements of list two are "links" and should be sortable. 
A link belongs to only one category. 
I want to move a link from a categerory to another and I would love to use JQuery Ui.

Comment: Can elements of list one be dragged to list two, and list two to list one? or is that what you are trying to prevent.

Comment: I tried to make the question as general as possible but maybe I should be more clear. Elements of list one are "catergories" and they should be sortable. Elements of list two are "links" and should be sortable. A link belongs to only one category. I want to move a link from a categerory to another and i would love to use JQuery Ui. I hope that now my problem is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not have to use `draggable` and `droppable` in conjunction with `sortable` in your case.

Sortable connections are inherently one-way, so you only have to connect the second list to the first, and avoid connecting the first to the second:

```
<ul id="first">
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>

<ul id="second">
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

---

```
$("#first").sortable();
$("#second").sortable({
    connectWith: "#first"
});
```

Comment: Hi Frederic, It's been long time since you wrote this answer. I have to say that you answer did not solve my problem but it actually solved my question :). that's because I did not wrote the question properly.